# Protobuf and Caffe in Xcode project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I have magic error with running fork of `Caffe` and `Protobuf` library version of 2.5.0.

> [libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:72] This program was compiled against version 2.4.1 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, which is not compatible with the installed version (2.5.0). Contact the program author for an update.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "/Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/fb4f05c74a361f59/External/common/ext/mapkit/routing/protobuf/RouterProtoFormat.pb.cc".)

The magic is that is no `RouterProtoFormat.pb.cc` anywhere on my computer. Google didn't know anything about this file.

Here [make file](https://github.com/molind/crosscompile) I used for build `protobuf` library. Any advice?

#### Edit

I decide include sources directly to project(without precompiled *.a library) and now I have another error:

> libprotobuf FATAL /Users/teamcity/buildAgent/work/fb4f05c74a361f59/External/lib/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:61] This program requires version 2.5.0 of the Protocol Buffer runtime library, but the installed version is 2.4.1.  Please update your library.  If you compiled the program yourself, make sure that your headers are from the same version of Protocol Buffers as your link-time library.  (Version verification failed in "project_dir/sources/caffe/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc".)

I setup debug breakpoint and seams that code executes in some hidden library. I can't get location of this library. I delete all libprotobuf.a files from computer and I still do not know witch file is executes..

#### Edit 2 (Solved)

There is only one solution I found. I rename everywhere `google` namespace to `google2`, and now seams all working fine.